# Is there any security benefit of "style-src 'self' 'nonce-rAnd0m'" over "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"?

Tags: css, security, content-security-policy, inline-styles

[This page](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-style/) lists using nonce as preferable to unsafe-inline for styles, but if everything besides style-src uses "default-src 'self'", is there any benefit to using nonce?

Answer (score 0):

The nonce based approach in the link you refer to is just an example, clearly you should use the nonce based approach for both styles and scripts.

This approach is called **strict CSP** and the advantage with using a nonce, is that you don't need to white-list all the domains. For example, check the CSP policy for twitter.com, its huge!

The CSP for Google docs looks like this, a pretty slim policy:

```
Content-Security-Policy: 
base-uri 'self';
object-src 'none';
report-uri https://docs.google.com/document/cspreport;
script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-Y7j7Ul3bnFVzbgVJ0-Tb7a' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'unsafe-eval';
worker-src 'self' blob:
```